# Acer Laptop is shutting off instantly when on battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, shutdown

My latop (Acer M5 581-TG) is  completely shutting off when on battery, sometimes before it can even attempt to boot, sometimes after 10 minutes of logging into windows. Everything is fine if it is plugged into a power source. There is no way for the button being pressed or the lid closing to initiate a shut down, let alone an instant shut-off. When my computer is plugged in this problem is non-existent.

So it *appears* to be a battery problem? Can I be sure of that? I am unable to touch or remove the battery due to the "ultra slim" build of the laptop. There is no exposed battery to see outside; the battery is inside and I am unable to open that without a lot of difficulty/special tools.

I have used the laptop for 7 months, mostly charged. I bought it in Bangkok and used it there and around Thailand. Sometimes without a surge protector.

Comment: It appears [Acer](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/standard-warranty) has at least a 1-year warranty on notebooks/netbooks. I'd suggest contacting them.

Comment: @CharlieRB I broke the warranty sticker covering the screw awhile back... I guess I can contact them anyway, but I'm not a fan of mailing the laptop in to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance shut off (rather than power down initiation) implies power loss, there are two direction I would have investigated - bad battery (e.g. due to age), or bad battery contact (or bad circutry). Your description makes me think the latter is more likely (unless your battery is over 2-4 years old). In any case, I don't think you'll be able to fully diagnose/fix without opening it up.

Comment: See updated answer, last paragraph about where it was bought/used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably not the battery but a badly implemented Acer design feature. On the reverse side, there are a series of T6 Torx screws. If the hardware detects any are open, it kills power as a "safety" feature. This is done to reduce the risk of a fire should the user open the case and turn on power to the laptop. This sounds nice, but the feature has been implemented poorly because the screws are self-loosing over time! Try tightening the screws hard. A Torx screwdriver (with changeable heads) can be picked up from a good hardware store for a few dollars.

This problem and resolution are [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).